# Hide specific code lines starting with {string} in Rider

Tags: c#, rider

I find that a lot of the telemetry code that I write often creates a lot of noise in my code files and is generally a bit of a nuisance. I'm looking for a way to hide specific lines in Rider if they start with a specific string.

For example if I had a lot of lines in my code that started with

```
_telemetryClient
```

Is there a way for me to turn off hiding and unhiding these lines?

I'm aware that `#region` exists, but Rider doesn't provide any hotkeys or quick ways to wrap code in a region and hide it. There's a menu you can click in the gutter but it's messy and ends up introducing empty lines for no reason.

If my request isn't possible, is there a way I can create a macro so that I can highlight a block of code and run the macro so that it automatically wraps the code with region tags, names the region and folds it?